Proverbs of Soloman and David?
Could Proverbs of Solomon be inspired by King David?
David is the father here in Chapter 4.

3 When I was a boy in my father's house, still tender, and an only child of my mother, 4 he taught me and said, "Lay hold of my words with all your heart; keep my commands and you will live. 5 Get wisdom, get understanding; do not forget my words or swerve from them. 6 Do not forsake wisdom, and she will protect you; love her, and she will watch over you. 7 Wisdom is supreme; therefore get wisdom. Though it cost all you have, get understanding. 8 Esteem her, and she will exalt you; embrace her, and she will honor you 9 She will set a garland of grace on your head and present you with a crown of splendor." [Proverbs-84 4:3-9 NIV] (emphasis mine)

The most interesting thing here is the couplet pattern. Solomon uses the same couplet style in the rest of Proverbs! In fact, the same Proverbs attributed to David here are repeated elsewhere in the book.
"Context Summary Proverbs 4:1–9 looks back on Solomon's childhood and the wise instruction he received from his father David. He rehearses that instruction and passes it along to his young students. Echoing David, Solomon credits wisdom..." (https://www.bibleref.com/Proverbs/4/Proverbs-4-3.html)

It is entirely possible that Solomon includes some proverbs that he learned from his father David.  I do not see that this is even remarkable.  Nothing in the book of Proverbs suggests that Solomon claimed that all the proverbs recorded there were original with him.  Some other sources are also quoted in later chapters such as Prov 31:1ff.

According to the book of Proverbs some of the content of the book did come from Solomon's father - David.
People often give Solomon credit for the whole of Proverbs but the book itself gives credit to others for parts of Proverbs.
Proverbs is a collection of Hebrew wisdom literature from different sources.
Content was handed down from David to Solomon - as noted in the question - and credited "to a father's instruction" in Proverbs 4:1 - 4.
In Proverbs we can find two other named contributors.
Content was also written by "Aguar son of Jakeh" and found in Proverbs 30:1 - 33.
Other content was written by "King Lemuel - an inspired utterance his mother taught him" found in Proverbs 31:1 - 9.
There is a collection of sayings - known as the Sayings of the Wise that run from Proverbs 22:17 - 24:34 which seem to be collected from an unnamed source.
